# Split day-of-month integers into digits, sum them repeatedly until get a single-digit integer

Tags: python, string, integer, digits, dayofmonth

I am attempting to take two-digit integers representing day-of-month, split the digits into single digits by taking each character in the single digit and adding them together to form a new number.

e.g. If the value for day was an integer 29, then the program would turn that into strings and split them into '2' and '9'. The program would then turn 2 and 9 into integers and add them together to equal 11. Since this is still a double digit number, the program would loop and 1 and 1 would be added together and the final value that would print would be 2. According to the code below(mostly the last ~5 lines), if I enter day=29, then the final answer I keep getting is 4 which is incorrect. Can someone help me fix this:

Note someone mentioned that I didn't re-enter dayStringSum and I accidentally deleted their post am not sure what that means at all.

```
 dayString = str(int(day))
# Turns value day into int
dayStringA = int(str(dayString[0]))
# If day=29 then this variable represents the 2...
dayStringB = int(str(dayString[1]))
# ...and this represents the 9
dayStringSum = (dayStringA + dayStringA)
while(dayStringSum >=10):
    dayStringA = int(str(dayStringSum[0]))
# Since daystringsum is now 11, this code changes the value of daystringA into a new value of 1, likewise for below.
    dayStringB = int(str(dayStringSum[1]))

print(dayStringSum)
```

Comment: To get the constituent digits of a two-digit number, you only need to do `for digit in str(day)`. None of this `dayStringA, dayStringB`

Comment: Then you can sum the digits with `day = sum(int(digit) for digit in str(day))`. And just wrap that in a loop `while day >= 10:` to repeatedly do the sum until you get a single digit. It's a two-liner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dayStringSum` is an integer, so `dayStringSum[n]` makes no sense. You'll want to turn it into a string first, and then look at its individual characters.

Also, you do not assign a new value to dayStringSum inside the `while` loop, so if it is >= 10 upon entering the loop, it will remain so, resulting in an infinite loop. You say that you got a final result of 4, but I fail to see how you would get a final result at all.

Try something like this:

```
daySum = int(day)  # Ensure that day is an int before we start.

while(daySum >= 10):
    newString = str(daySum)
    dayIntA = int(newString[0])
    dayIntB = int(newString[1])
    daySum = dayIntA + dayIntB  # Will be checked on next iteration.

print(daySum)
```

Comment: for the second final line, do you mean dayIntA instead of dayStringA, because if not, then I fail to see how the 3 statements above it have any value? I am very new to programming and trying my best. Please forgive me if it seemes like ignorance on my part.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I mean. Good catch! :-) I've edited it now.

Comment: next question refers to the statements within the "while"
So the first line creates a new variable which makes the value of daysum into a string. The second and third lines split the string and convert it into integers, the last line adds the integers and gives a new value for daysum. right? If so, then what I don't understand is, if after the number is reduced the reduced number is again a double digit say 12, then why would the program look at the new value of daysum (given through last line of "while". instead of just going back to the statement above the "while" statement(in my question)?

Comment: yes yes yes! I finally got it, thank you so much. I've made too many silly mistakes that screw me over. Damn tunnel vision. This post was the most helpful to me. Thank you so very much!

Comment: @user1716168 It's recommended to accept the answer that best addresses your problem, if there is one. (Click the green checkmark)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the reason you're getting the wrong answer is that you add `dayStringA + dayStringA` when you meant to add `dayStringA + dayStringB`, i.e. it's just a typo.

The other thing you need to fix is that in the loop, you don't change `dayStringSum`. This hasn't been a problem so far because `dayStringSum` is less than 10 in your example, so the loop never executes in the first place, but once you fix that typo, you're going to get an infinite loop and the program will never stop.

Here's what I mean: suppose your day is `29`. When you get to this line:

```
while(dayStringSum >=10):
```

then `dayStringSum` will be 11. So then you set `dayStringA` to 1,

```
    dayStringA= int(str(dayStringSum[0]))
```

and also `dayStringB` to 1.

```
    dayStringB= int(str(dayStringSum[1]))
```

Then that's the end of the loop. So Python goes back to this line:

```
while(dayStringSum >=10):
```

What's `dayStringSum`? Why, it's still 11! You never changed it. So Python will keep looping, going through the same logic over and over again.

Now beyond that, there are a bunch of things that make this code *way* more complicated than it needs to be. I'm not going to go through them ([Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) would be the place for that), but in general, you don't need to convert things to `int`s if they are already `int`s, and likewise you don't need to use `str` on something that is already a string.

Comment: wow I have just understood loops so much better than the textbook or the professor explained it. Thank you very much. Let me get to a high enough level and im coming back to give you a +1

Answer (score 0):

try `sum(map(int,"265"))`

that maps them to ints and sums them ...

```
>>> sum(map(int,"254"))
11
```

or

```
>>> sum(map(int,str(29)))
11
```

oh well since its homework I cant really just give away the answer ....

but

its similar to

```
sum1=0
for integer in [1,2,3]: sum1 += integer
print sum1
```

Comment: I cant use anything more than really what I have above. We are studying beginner python and I cant use sum or map. I need to integrate looping.

Comment: we cannot utilize for statements either. Neither do I understand the codes map, for, and in, above. I am not asking for the answer but I believe there is some format error that I just can't notice. I've been changing the above constantly for the last 4 hrs trying to figure it out to no avail.

Comment: `map(int,"265")` is less preferred than a list comprehension or generator expression `[int(digit) for digit in "265"]`. But anyway we can fold all that into a generator expression: `sum(int(digit) for digit in str(day))`

Comment: why is it less preferrable? and to who?

Answer (score 0):

Easier way is to take modulus 9 of the number

```
>>> print(29%9)
2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
day = 29

while day >= 10:
    day = sum(int(digit) for digit in str(day))
```

(Also, whenever you're doing major manipulations of the individual digits of an integer, `decimal.Decimal` is useful, in particular its method
`Decimal(29).as_tuple().digits` which gives you `(2, 9)`).